# void() function return a value instead of char or string?

Tags: c++

this is my code that I have been working for quite a while. I got stuck mainly on my

```
void displayProblem(int operand1, int operand2, char getOperator)
{
cout << " operand1 getOperator operand2 = ";
}
```

saying ('displayProblem' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int (__cdecl *)(int)' to 'int') then another one

```
int doIt(int operand1, int operand2, char getOperator)
{
    result = (operand1 getOperator operand2);

    return result;
}
```

the error say ('doIt' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int (__cdecl *)(int)' to 'int') It also say "result" is undeclared identifier
I wonder what did I do wrong...

Here is my code

```
//This program is a mathematical question generator.
//By asking user to enter 2 separate value from 1 - 100
//This program will generate a problem which involved addition, subtraction, amultiplication

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void displayProblem(int, int, char);

int main()
{
    bool checkGuess(int, int);
    char getOperator(int);
    int operand1(int);
    int operand2(int);
    int doIt(int, int, char);

    srand(time(NULL));
    int max;
    int result;
    int answer;
    int correctAnswer;

    //make the program run 10 times
    for( int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
    {
        //prompt user to enter positive value to generate random number up to entered value
        cout << "Please enter value from 0 - 100" << endl;
        cin >> max;

        //check for validity of entered value
        while((max < 0) || (max > 100))
        {
            cout << "Error. Please enter value from 0 - 100" << endl;
            cin >> max;
        }

        //prompt user to enter positive value to generate random number up to entered value
        cout << "Please enter value from 0 - 100" << endl;
        cin >> max;

        //check for validity of entered value
        while((max < 0) || (max > 100))
        {
            cout << "Error. Please enter value from 0 - 100" << endl;
            cin >> max;
        }

        //display the problem
        displayProblem(operand1, getOperator, operand2);

        cout << endl;

        //prompt user to enter the answer
        cout << "Please enter your answer. ";
        cin >> answer ;

        //display the correct answer
        cout << "The right answer is " << doIt(operand1, operand2, getOperator) << endl;

        //determine whether the answer is right or wrong
        checkGuess(result, answer);

        if(result == answer)
        {
            correctAnswer += 1;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "You got " << correctAnswer << " numbers correct." << endl;
}

//function to get the first random number
int operand1(int max)
{
    int number1;
    number1 = rand() % max;
    return number1;
}

//function to get the second random number
int operand2(int max)
{
    int number2;
    number2 = rand() % max;
    return number2;
}

//function to get a random char for mathematical operation
char getOperator(int randOperator)
{
    randOperator = rand() % 3;

    if(randOperator = 0)
    {
        cout << '+';
    }else if(randOperator = 1)
    {
        cout << '-';
    }else
    {
        cout << '*';
    }

    return randOperator;
}

//function to solve the problem
int doIt(int operand1, int operand2, char getOperator)
{
    result = (operand1 getOperator operand2);

    return result;
}

//function to show the problem
void displayProblem(int operand1, int operand2, char getOperator)
{
    cout << " operand1 getOperator operand2 = ";
}

//function to check for correct answer
bool checkGuess(int result, int answer)
{
    if(answer == result)
    {
        cout << "You are correct. " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Your are wrong. " << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yeah? `operand1` is a function (inside `main`), `doIt` does not take a function as a parameter, so `doIt(operand1, ...` makes no sense.

Comment: The requirement say **int doIt(int operand1 ,int operand2,  char operate = '+')** This function is to perform the operation indicated by the parameter values, and return the result. Note this this function may be called with two or three arguments. If only two arguments are passed, the function uses the default as indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void displayProblem(int, int, char);
 bool checkGuess(int, int);
    char getOperator(int);
    int operand(int); 
    int doIt(int, int, char);

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    int max;
    int result;
    int answer;
    int correctAnswer = 0;

    //make the program run 10 times
    for( int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
    {         

        //check for validity of entered value
        do
        {
            cout << "Error. Please enter value from 0 - 100" << endl;
            cin >> max;
        } while((max < 0) || (max > 100));

    // getting the operands and operators
        int op1 = operand(max);
        int op2 = operand(max);
        char opert = getOperator(max); 

        //display the problem
        displayProblem(op1,op2,opert);
        result = doIt(op1, op2, opert);
        cout << endl;

        //prompt user to enter the answer
        cout << "Please enter your answer. \t" << endl;
        cin >> answer ;

        //display the correct answer
        cout << "The right answer is\t "<< result <<endl;

        //determine whether the answer is right or wrong 

        if(checkGuess(result, answer))
        {
            correctAnswer++;
            cout << "Your score is : " << correctAnswer;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "You got " << correctAnswer << " numbers correct." << endl;
}

//function to get the first random number
int operand(int max)
{
    int number1;
    number1 = rand() % max;
    return number1;
} 

//function to get a random char for mathematical operation
char getOperator(int randOperator)
{
    randOperator = rand() % 3;

    if(randOperator == 0)
        return '+'; /* If condition true function returs here */
    if(randOperator == 1) 
        return '-'; /* If condition true function returs here */
    return '*'; /* both If condition fails function returs here */
}

//function to solve the problem
int doIt(int operand1, int operand2, char getOperator)
{
    int result;  

// doin appropriate operation
    switch(getOperator)
    {
        case '+':   
                    result = operand1 + operand2 ;
                    break;
        case '-':
                    result = operand1 - operand2 ;
                    break;
        case '*':
                    result = operand1 * operand2 ;
                    break; 
    }


    return result;
} 

//function to show the problem
void displayProblem(int operand1, int operand2, char getOperator)
{
    cout << "Qn : \t" << operand1 <<"\t" << getOperator <<"\t" << operand2  << endl;
}

//function to check for correct answer
bool checkGuess(int result, int answer)
{
    if(answer == result)
    {
        cout << "You are correct. " << endl;
        return true;
    }
    cout << "Your are wrong. " << endl; 
    return false;
}
```

Here is the complete code, Proper comments are added,

Comment: are these supposed to be in my displayProblem()?

Comment: Ya, I have compiled your code and there was no compilation error :)

Comment: That is fine, there are more issues I can able find in your code, I will try to fix it

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your time and effort for helping me out

Answer (score 1):

1. The function displayProblem expects to take in a parameter list with the types (int, int, char). Rather than passing it ints, you are passing it the names of functions that return ints, plus you are passing the parameters in the wrong order. To get the integer values from this function, you need to call it using parentheses and passing it parameters. In other words, instead of

   ```
   displayProblem(operand1, getOperator, operand2);
   ```

   you should have

   ```
   displayProblem(operand1(max), operand2(max), getOperator(max));
   ```

   As an aside, there isn't a good reason for getOperator to take in a parameter since it doesn't use it, but your code should run fine doing that anyway.
2. The reason that result is an undeclared identifier is because you never declared that variable. To declare the variable, you need to put its type first:

   ```
   int result;
   ```
3. Beyond that, C++ doesn't know how to interpret:

   ```
   (operand1 getOperator operand2);
   ```

   You'll need to split it up into different cases, e.g.

   ```
   int doIt(int operand1, int operand2, char getOperator)
   {
       int result;
       if(getOperator == '+')
       {
           result = operand1 + operand2;
       }
       if(getOperator == '-')
       {
           result = operand1 - operand2;
       }
       if(getOperator == '*')
       {
           result = operand1 * operand2;
       }
       //and so on
       return result;
   }
   ```

Comment: Chris, I got confused on the getOperator(). Why I must put 'max' inside the bracket for getOperator() to become getOperator(max). I didn't generate random number based on the int max like I did on operand1 and operand2.

Comment: Also,   `//display the correct answer
  cout << "The right answer is " << doIt(operand1, operand2, getOperator) << endl;` I got error saying **'doIt' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int (__cdecl *)(int)' to 'int'** what is that mean?

Comment: "Why I must put 'max' inside the bracket for getOperator() to become getOperator(max)".
Let's look at the function header: char getOperator(int randOperator).
The getOperator function is expecting an int parameter. You must pass it some parameter to match the signature of this function. Since you never use the value of randOperator, you can pass whatever value you want. You could pass 0 if you want. But you need to pass some integer, OR remove that parameter from the function declaration/definition.

Comment: "I got error saying 'doIt' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int (__cdecl *)(int)' to 'int' what is that mean?" See my #1 above. The function takes in an int as the first parameter. operand1 is not an int, it is a function. The error message means it cannot convert from a function to an int.

Comment: Thank you for you help Chris. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to pass a function a parameter to the displayProblem().
But the function only accepts 'int', try passing a integer to displayProblem() as
      `displayProblem(number1,number2,getOperator);` or

```
displayProblem(operator1(int),operator2(int),getOperator);
```

Comment: when I put displayProblem(number1, getOperator, number2). I got error message saying number1 number2: undeclared identifier.

Comment: use the second line, because, you have not declared the number1,number2 in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

These lines

```
int operand1(int);
int operand2(int);
```

declare `operand1` and `operand2` as two functions that take an `int` input and return `int`.

You cannot use `operand1` where an `int` is expected. You need to replace that by a call to `operand1` with an appropriate argument. Your call to `displayProblem`:

```
    displayProblem(operand1, getOperator, operand2);
```

needs to be changed to:

```
    displayProblem(operand1(max), operand2(max), getOperator(some argument));
```

I don't know what will be a good argument to `getOperator`. It seems like it doesn't need an argument at all. You should be able to change it to:
    // Declaration.
    char getOperator();

```
// Definition.
char getOperator()
{
    int randOperator = rand() % 3;

    // This is an error.
    // if(randOperator = 0)
    // It should be
    if(randOperator == 0)    {

        // Also, I think you want to return '+`, not just print it.
        cout << '+';

    // Also an error
    // }else if(randOperator = 1)
    // It should be
    }else if(randOperator == 1)
    {
        cout << '-';
    }else
    {
        cout << '*';
    }

    return randOperator;
}
```

Given, that change you can use

```
    displayProblem(operand1(max), operand2(max), getOperator());
```

I'll let you figure out changes in other places to fix the compiler errors.

Comment: the getOperator() causes error. Somehow Chris Usher say put **getOperator(max)** the error is gone. Now the only problem is my output for answer in my main code where is display the answer for the mathematical operation `cout << "The right answer is " << doIt(operand1, operand2, getOperator) << endl;' this cause error saying **'doIt' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int (__cdecl *)(int)' to 'int'**. I got confused, what is that even mean?